# Changing to kpfonts

Tags: packages, kpfonts

I am editing a document in Texmaker and am fairly new to LaTeX. I am using the output PDFLaTeX/view PDF. I added the `kpfonts` package to my document to change the font:

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and got the following error:

```
! LateX Error: File 'kpfonts.sty' not found.
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `kpfonts` is not installed. Use the manager of your TeX distribution to install it. It is available with the same name in TeX Live and MiKTeX.

Comment: How to I get it from this? I don't see a download link http://miktex.org/packages/kpfonts

Comment: @outworlddevourer: MiKTeX has a package manager. It should list `kpfonts`. Select and install it.

Comment: Is it on the software? I'm confused on what to do with it... I installed MikTeX and it doesn't open. I can't find any links on their main website.

Comment: See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution/55473#55473).

Comment: @outworlddevourer: Startmenu → MiKTeX 2.9 → Maintenance → Package Manager. MiKTeX documentation: [Working With the Package Manager](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/pkgmgt.html).